# How to run a clojure program in repl

Tags: clojure

(ns onyx.core

(:require [onyx.api]

[onyx.plugin.datomic]

(:import [com.mchange.v2.c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource]))

(def onyx-id (java.util.UUID/randomUUID))

I have a clojure project as above. I want to run the file in repl. How do I do it terminal?

lein repl

user=> (require..?)

what should be used there to get the onyx-id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your REPL, you should be able to

- Require that namespace

  ```
  (require '[onyx.core])
  => nil
  ```
- Evaluate the var

  ```
  onyx.core/onyx-id
  => #uuid "f1d49b2a-dfaa-4ea5-99a5-4af7ef0ce9b7"
  ```